# Shouldn't this statement end with an error?

Tags: sql, sqlite, create-table, union-all

Consider the `SELECT` statement below:

```sql
SELECT 1, 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C';
```

The result is obvious:

```
1    'A'
2    'B'
3    'C'
```

I tried to store it as a separate table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp AS
    SELECT 1, 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'C';
```

The contents of the `tmp` table are surprising:

```
1    'A'
2    'A'
3    'A'
```

Ok, that can be fixed providing explicit field names:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp AS
    SELECT 1 AS field1, 'A' AS field2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'C';
```

Now I have a question whether the observed behavior is defined and valid. I feel that the statement without explicit field names should end with an error instead of producing a surprising result.

I'm using SQLite.

Comment: It's very interesting, what's your DB's version ? No problem seems with [3.39](https://dbfiddle.uk/AQVCUKd0)

Comment: I'm using SQLiteStudio v3.1.0. What is the result the version 3.39 produces?

Comment: Hi, already shared on the above link which refers a demo.